# Why does `make` 4.4 behave like it does with shell calls and `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've encountered a really strange problem with one of our `Makefile`s and have the reduced it to a minimal example.

#### Setup

1. In a directory, I've put the following `Makefile`:

```
MYVAR1 ?= $(shell echo "echo")
MYVAR2 ?= $(shell $(MYVAR1) ./file)

.PHONY: all

all:
        @echo $(MYVAR2)

.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:
```

2. In the same directory I've `touch`ed a file called `file`, making sure its permissions are 0660 (the important part being no executable bit)
3. To ensure clean-room experiment, I've started two Docker containers separately:

- `docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/src -w /src ubuntu:22.04` with the followup of `apt-get update && apt-get install -y make`
- `docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/src -w /src archlinux` with the followup of `pacman -Syy && pacman -S make`

4. Additionally, since Ubuntu contains `make` 4.3 while Archlinux contains 4.4.1 I've downloaded `make` 4.4.1 tarball, compiled a binary and copied it into running Ubuntu container at `/tmp/make`.

#### Execution

- Running `make` in the Ubuntu container only produces target's output, as intended:

```
root@0bb1bf858e2a:/src# make
./file
```

- Running `make` in the Archlinux container produces a "Permission denied" error while still executing the target:

```
[root@ad0d96a85e9b src]# make
make: ./file: Permission denied
./file
```

- Running `/tmp/make` in the Ubuntu container also produces a "Permission denied" error while still executing the target:

```
root@0bb1bf858e2a:/src# /tmp/make
make: ./file: Permission denied
./file
```

#### Thoughts

Fiddling with execution bits, I could conclude that the "permission denied" error results from `make` trying to execute `./file`. This should only happen if `$(MYVAR2)` is unset or empty (basically resulting in `$(shell ./file)`), which it's not, as proven by the `all` target. Also, both `$(shell)` calls are required for the setup to work.

The problem disappears when `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` target is removed. It also seems that `make` 4.4 makes the difference, since it's the only version where this problem occurs. The changelog for 4.4 states the following in connection to `$(shell ...)` and exports:

> - WARNING: Backward-incompatibility!
>   Previously makefile variables marked as export were not exported to commands
>   started by the $(shell ...) function.  Now, all exported variables are
>   exported to $(shell ...).  If this leads to recursion during expansion, then
>   for backward-compatibility the value from the original environment is used.
>   To detect this change search for 'shell-export' in the .FEATURES variable.

While I suspect that this is the change I'm stumbling over, I'm not quite sure how exactly it's relevant and why this happens.

Can you explain what's happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` has nothing to do with it.  `$(MYVAR1)` in the second `$(shell ...)` is expanded by `make`, before the command is handed off to a shell.  And if it were not, then in the shell it would be a command substitution, not a parameter expansion.

Comment: It seems unlikely, but do you by any chance have an environment variable `MYVAR1` defined in the context from which you launch `make`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger the variable isn't even called `MYVAR1` originally, I have renamed it in the test setup to avoid possible name clashes.

Comment: Do you see different behavior if you assign `MYVAR1`'s value with `=` or `:=` instead of with `?=`?

Comment: It might be illustrative to see what each `make` outputs if you insert this between the definitions of the two variables:  `$(info MYVAR1 = $(MYVAR1) (from $(origin MYVAR1)))`

Comment: It might also be illustrative to see whether it makes a difference to define `MYVAR1` without using `$(shell)`.  That is, just `MYVAR1 = echo` (or with `:=` or with `?=`).  And maybe also to use `make -d` to get some debugging information.  I'm suggesting these variations because I suspect that you are observing a regression in Make 4.4, not it's intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a bug.  This is especially because if you add `-d` you'll see multiple messages about variables being skipped (which might be correct, or not, but at the least it's odd that you see the same message multiple times).  You could file an issue on Savannah about it then someone will look to make a decision: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=make&func=additem

Without minimizing the regression, I'll say that this makefile has problems.

By using `?=` here these variables are recursive, which means you're ensuring that these shells are run many times throughout your makefile.  Instead of this I recommend you use `ifeq` and only set the value, using simple expansion, if the value is empty, like this:

```
ifeq ($(MYVAR1),)
  MYVAR1 := $(shell echo "echo")
endif
ifeq ($(MYVAR2),)
  MYVAR2 := $(shell $(MYVAR1) ./file)
endif
```

Note this is subtly different than your original because your original makefile would leave `MYVAR1` and `MYVAR2` as empty if you had an empty value in the environment, like this:

```
$ MYVAR1=  make
```

would leave the make variable `MYVAR1` empty, while my version above would replace it with the output of the `$(shell ...)`.  If you need the original behavior you can use `$(origin ...)` to test for that; there's an example exactly like this in the GNU Make manual.  But my suspicion is based on what you've written that you never want these values to be empty anyway.

If you make the above change it will work the same way (and be faster to boot) in all versions of GNU Make.

Also as an aside, IMO `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is a terrible feature and should only ever be used for quick hacks, never for any sort of "production" makefile.  It's entirely too dangerous (not even counting this issue) and can lead to very difficult to find problems in some situations.  If you need some variables exported you should export them explicitly by name so it's clear.  Of course, this won't solve your problem above if you really DO want to export `MYVAR1` and `MYVAR2`: the makefile above doesn't need to but maybe you do in your real makefile.